# Modifying Exchange ACL for folders with python

Tags: python, exchange-server, mapi, pywin32

while try to read the ACL Table of a folder, I ran into this problem:

In a C++ tool (MFCMAPI) this method is used to get the Property PR_ACL_TABLE in a usable data type:

```
// Open the table in an IExchangeModifyTable interface
 EC_H(lpMAPIProp->OpenProperty(
  ulPropTag,
  (LPGUID)&IID_IExchangeModifyTable,
  0,
  MAPI_DEFERRED_ERRORS,
  (LPUNKNOWN FAR *)&lpExchTbl));
```

I figured out to do this in python win32:

```
table = mystore.OpenProperty(mapitags.PR_ACL_TABLE, IID_IExchangeModifyTable, 0 , mapi.MAPI_DEFERRED_ERRORS)
```

But it seems that the MAPI Extension does not know the IID_IExchangeModifyTable type. I just got just this error:

*AttributeError: `'module' object has no attribute 'IID_IExchangeModifyTable`'*

Does anybody know another way to get and modify the ACL data from exchange via the MAPI (and python)?

Thanks
- Marquies

Comment: Just an idea : did you try to generate this type with the win32 com makepy utility? Not sure because I don't have exchange installed and not very familliar with this API. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyIMAPIProp__OpenProperty_meth.html), you need a PyIID object.

> However, in almost all cases,
>   functions that expect a CLSID/IID as a
>   param will accept either a string
>   object, or a native PyIID object.

That said, I've seen **mapi.IID_IMessage** used with the OpenProperty method.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the I tried mapi.IID_IExchangeModifyTable before, maybe it is just a copy&paste error on my side. The problem is that the Python MAPI has no implementation for the IID_IExchangeModifyTable interface. This is confirmed on the bugtracker: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3058134&group_id=78018&atid=551954

Answer (score 1):

`IExchangeModifyTable` is declared in edkmdb.h
Are you using mapi33 in python? Is that interface even declared in mapi33?
You can use `RDOFolder.ACL` in Redemption (I am its author): http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/RDOACL.htm

Comment: Thanks for the edkmdb.h hint. I used some libs from MFCMAPI to write an extension of pywin32 mapi to get this work. I will contribute it to the project, let's see if it is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the ACL table on a message store object.  As far as I know, ACL tables are specific to folder objects and don't exist on message stores.  Try using your "mystore" object to open a particular folder within the store, and then call OpenProperty on the folder object to retrieve the ACL table. Make sure you open the folder object with the MAPI_NO_CACHE and MAPI_MODIFY flags specified as well.